# How can I add my web scrape process using bs4 to selenium automation in Python to make it one single process which just asks for a zipcode?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium to go to a website and then go to the search button type a zipcode which I am entering beforehand and then for that zip code I want the link that the webpage has to feed my web scraper created using beautiful soup and once the link comes up I can scrape required data to get my csv.

What I want:
I am having trouble getting that link to the beautiful soup URL. I basically want to automate it so that I just have to enter a zip code and it gives me my CSV.

What I am able to get:
I am able to enter the zip code and search using selenium and then add that url to my **scraper** to give csv.

**Code I am using for selenium :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/akashgupta/Desktop/Courses and Learning/Automating Python and scraping/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.weather.gov/')
messageField = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inputstring"]')
messageField.click()
messageField.send_keys('75252')
time.sleep(3)
showMessageButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnSearch"]')
showMessageButton.click()


#web scraping Part:


url="https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=32.99802500000004&lon=-96.79775499999994#.Xo5LnFNKgWo"
res= requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
tag=soup.find_all('div',id='seven-day-forecast-body')
weekly=soup.find_all(class_='tombstone-container')
main=soup.find_all(class_='period-name')
description=soup.find_all(class_='short-desc')
temp=soup.find_all(class_='temp')
Period_Name=[]
Desc=[]
Temp=[]
for a in range(0,len(main)):
    Period_Name.append(main[a].get_text())
    Desc.append(description[a].get_text())
    Temp.append(temp[a].get_text())
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Period_Name, Desc,Temp)),columns =['Period_Name', 'Short_Desc','Temperature'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.weather.gov/')
messageField = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inputstring"]')
messageField.click()
messageField.send_keys('75252')
time.sleep(3)
showMessageButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnSearch"]')
showMessageButton.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_contains("https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php")) # here you are waiting until url will match your output pattern

currentURL = driver.current_url
print(currentURL)
time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()

#web scraping Part:

res= requests.get(currentURL)
....
```

Comment: Thank You @sammyyy .This worked perfectly. Can you suggest some good selenium sources to understand selenium in deep.?